# Excel IF A1 exist in column B, then C = D

Tags: excel

I have an issue.

In excel I need If value from A column exit in column B, then I need to take value from C from same row as B and put it same row as A. I can do it manually but it is a lot of work for me. Maybe someone have formula, because what I was able to find it was only return true or false. Maybe someone know other tool to do it.

Comment: If you are trying to overwrite the cell in `Column A` based off the value that currently exists in `Column A`, then you will need `VBA`. In excel, you will need a helper column. It's also not exactly clear what your output should be. Can you upload a photo of some sample data? Show what your output should look like given the data you show

Answer (score 0):

In **D1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

An error message will appear in **D1** if the value can't be found.  To avoid the error message use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B:C,2,FALSE),"")
```

instead.